# Cannot connect database to prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have ASP.NET API application and I want to use this data for Prometheus. 
My API link which returns Json data `https://localhost:44361/api/Authors`
At the moment I have stuck configurating `prometheus.yml` I added `scheme`, `metrics_path`, changed `targets` but the result I am getting after I click on `http://localhost:9090/targets` endpoint `https://localhost:44361/api/authors` is 
 `https://desktop-5lf9021:44361/api/authors` and the error message is

```
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    scheme: https
    metrics_path: '/api/authors'

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:44361']
```

How can I get the right data?

Answer (score 0):

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>   HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

This is a problem with your application, you presumably need to fix it to ignore the `Host` header for these requests.